# Prevent iframe redirecting externally on form submit

Tags: iframe, onclick, submit

My login form is in an iframe on my website and automatically sends people to the desired welcome page on correct submission.

If, however, the password is entered incorrectly, the iframe goes to an external url saying incorrect password, try again - or words of that effect.

What I need is on incorrect submission, some way of preventing the iframe from loading the external url and forcing it to load my own page in the iframe.

I'm wondering about various possible ways of doing this but have little to no coding knowledge.

1 option may be that on submission (or fractionally after), it activates some code on the main page telling it to load my own page in the iframe.  The theory is that on correct submission, the welcome page has loaded before the iframe has had a chance to reload.

another option could be that on submission, some code linked to the submit button (onclick or similar) reloads to page in the frame or a page of my choice before it's had a chance to load externally - again on correct submission going to the welcome page before having a chance to reload.

Does this sound at all possible??

current code is...

```
<form action="http://www.othersite.com/action=login&amp;base=" method="post" style="margin: 0">
<div class="border" style="padding: 12px; width: 80%; margin: 0">
<h3 class="font">Login</h3>
<label class="font2" style="display: block" for="username">Email</label>
<input class="font2" name="username" tabindex="1" id="username" style="width: 100%; color: black">
<label class="font2" style="display: block" for="password">Password</label>
<input class="font2" type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" id="password" style="width: 100%">
<div style="padding-top: 0px">
<br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="font3 button" tabindex="3">
    </div>


</div>
</form>
```

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: You should try to post the full working code rather than just a small snippet of markup

Comment: not sure how you add code but i'll try